# C++ call function does not successfully call a function

Tags: c++

I am developing a program in which allows the user to write to, read from and append a text file. I have decided to use function for this rather than many if else statements within one main function (I like structure). However, I seem to be unable to get the function calls to call upon the functions. I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

When using `cin >> choice` the program terminates when a selection is input.

When using `scanf_s("\n%c", &choice)` the program states incorrect input before terminating.

I am using VSE 2013.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> //C++ header file for input/output
#include <iostream> //C++ header file for input/output
#include <conio.h> // include library for pause function
#include <fstream> //for both read and write functionality
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//--------------------WRITE FUNCTION-----------------------------

int write()//main function 
    cout << "You have opted to write to the file.";

    string x;
ofstream mynewfile;
//open output file stream
    mynewfile.open("testC++.txt");
    //use ofstream object to open file created within paranethesis
    mynewfile << "I have a hairy butt.\n";
    //push the above char data to the file
    cout << "Please write something: \n";//outputs
    //  std::string x;//store input as x, already declared string
    mynewfile << x;//write input to file
    mynewfile.close();
    //close file on execution for resources purposes
    return 0;
    // '0' is returned as a 'success flag'  
//---------------------APPEND FUNCTION--------------------------------

int append()
{
    string x;
    ofstream mynewfile;
    ifstream read;
    ofstream append;
    string line;
    cout << "You have opted to append the text file.";
    append.open("testC++.text", ios::app);
    cin >> x;
    append << x << "  ";
    append.close();
    read.open("testC++.text");
    if (read.is_open())//if read is open

{
        while (getline(read, line))
{
            cout << line << "\n";//output file to screen
}
        append.close();
}
    else cout << "Unable to append file. \n"; //else 
    return (0);

//------------------------READ FUNCTION-------------------------------------

int read()
{
    ifstream read;
    string line;
read.open("testC++.text");//open text file
if (read.is_open())//if text file is open
    while (getline(read, line))
{
        cout << line << "\n";//output file to screen
}
    read.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to read the file. \n"; // else error message
return (0);
//--------------MAIN FUNCTION----------------------------------------------------
int main()
//declare main function
{
    int choice;
    ofstream write;
    //declare writer as ofstream
    ifstream read;
    //declaire read as ifstream
    ofstream append;
    //declare ofstream as append;
    cout << "1. Write to file.\n";
    //output to screen to prompt user for their choice of task
    cout << "2. Append to file.\n";
    cout << "3. Display the text file.\n";
    cout << "4. Exit the program.\n";
    cout << "Please select the operation you wish to carry out by selcting the corresponsing number\n";
    scanf_s("\n%c", &choice); // trying to get the function calls to work I tried scanf_s(states incorrent input)
    //cin >> choice; --- origional input method (program just terminates)
    //declare choice as user input
if (choice == 1)
write;
//if user input = 1 call write function
else if (choice == 2)
append;
// if user input = 2 call read function
else if (choice == 3)
read;
//if user input = 3 call read function
else if (choice == 4)
//cout << "The program will now quit. \n";
void _exit( //_exir function termites calling process in LIFO order.
void _exit( //_exir function termites calling process in LIFO order.
);
else if (choice != 4 || choice > 4)
cout << "incorrect value entered, please enter a value from 1-4";
//if user input = 4 call exit function
return 0;
system("pause"); // not the best way I am aware
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//program ends
```

Comment: You post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we probably _"bear with you"_. Not so far yet.

Comment: I recommend you switch back to `cin` and use a debugger to see what happens after that statement.

Comment: Are you sure you can compile your code? It doesn't look like C++ code.

Comment: "I liked `iostream` so much, I included it *twice*."  Review your include files and get rid of that `stdafx` header file!

Comment: what's all the `void _exit(` stuff?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the stdafx.h is required if visual studio is in use

Comment: @tim3880, yes it compiles.  - 'stdafx.h' is necessary as I am using VS.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (choice == 1)
write;
//if user input = 1 call write function
else if (choice == 2)
append;
// if user input = 2 call read function
else if (choice == 3)
read;
//if user input = 3 call read function
```

These statements don't call functions. In fact they don't really do anything at all.

To call the `write` function you need to do `write();` and similarly for the others.

---

However taking a further look back at your code you also have

```
ofstream write;
//declare writer as ofstream
ifstream read;
//declaire read as ifstream
ofstream append;
//declare ofstream as append;
```

You have variables with the same names as your functions... that's just going to be a mess and may prevent you from being able to call the functions properly in the first place.

Clean up your naming so they don't overlap. Then call the functions with the appropriate syntax.

Comment: s/may/will. The local variables shadow the functions.

Comment: Thank you, I realized the issue with the missing parenthesis a little while ago, I have also changed the name of the functions to writeToFile(), appendToFile() and readFromFile() so that they no longer  conflict. I've also taken Thomas Matthew's advice and reverted back to cin. l My write function seems to be working fine now, although the other two are not doing anything.